# L3 leaf-spine architecture and DHCP ip assignment

Tags: vlan, dhcp, ecmp, vxlan

Background: we are planning to have a L3 leaf spine network with TOR(redundant mlag) and spine switch.

Each TOR is on a specific subnet and run bgp with spine. Now, what is the recommendation to run DHCP server. Generally, if it is a flat L2 domain, we can run the DHCP anywhere and get IPs irrespective of subnet etc. But how to configure a management leaf and run DHCP under it and issue ips based on the subnet to every rack? Is there any connection between vlan/vxlan in this context?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be to use a DHCP relay agent on your core switch/router. Configure this under each vlan interface and point it to your DHCP server. The DHCP discoveries will only stay on the LAN segment so you need a relay agent so that the broadcast can be turned into a unicast and routed to the vlan or even external IP address to offer an IP address.

Make sure you create scopes on your DHCP server that matches the subnet that the device is requesting an IP address from.

If you specify what networking gear you are using we can help you more with the specific configuration.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan